# Question regarding the monotonicity of Mutual Information of a tripartite state under multiple non-local commuting unitaries

Tags: quantum-operation, mutual-information

Given a system $\rho_{AB}\otimes\rho_{C}$, and a unitary interaction $U_{BC}$, due to the monotonicity of the relative entropy under the actions of the partial trace map, $$I(A:B)=I(A:U_{BC}(B,C))\ge I(A:N(C))$$, where $N()$ is the local channel on subsystem $C$, after tracing out $B$, correct?

I am aware most proofs usually trace out the initially uncorrelated system, and the upper bound would usually involve the local channel, but unless I have been misunderstanding something for a while now, I believe this should still hold.

I ask because, if we now consider a unitary $U_{AC}$, that commutates with $U_{BC}$, so either interaction could be performed first.

In this case, I have assumed that $$I(A'':B',C'')=I(A':U_{BC}(B,C'))$$ where $I(A':U_{BC}(B,C'))$ is is obtained via the mutual information of $U_{AC}(\rho_{AB}\otimes\rho_{C})$, with the local operations $U_{BC}$ unable to change the mutual information.

I would therefor expect that $$I(A':U_{BC}(B,C'))=I(A':B,C')$$ where the only interaction is between $A$ and $C$  using $U_{AC}$. As such, $$I(A':B,C')\ge I(A':N(C'))$$ where $N$ is the reduced map from the actions of $U_{BC}$. As such, I would expect $$I(A':C') \ge I(A':N(C'))$$

However, a calculation I have done, is giving me $$I(A':N(C'))>I(A':C').$$

So I would like to know two things:

- If my first inequality, which I can find no reason to be wrong, is correct? I have always though it is, however I am now doubting myself because of the second inequality.
- How is $I(A':N(C'))>I(A':C')?$

I have checked the results, and the marginal states are valid density matrices, and the mutual information is being calculated the correct way, so I am at a bit of a loss as to how this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the relative entropy between two states $\rho$ and $\sigma$ as
$$
D(\rho\|\sigma) := \mathrm{tr}[\rho(\log \rho - \log \sigma)]\,.
$$
Then we can write a the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$ for the state $\rho_{XY}$ as
$$
I(X:Y) = D(\rho_{XY} \|\rho_X \otimes \rho_Y)\,.
$$
Notice also that the relative entropy satisfies a data processing inequality
$$
D(\rho\|\sigma) \geq D(\mathcal{N}(\rho) \|\mathcal{N}(\sigma))\,.
$$

Taking the quantum channel $\mathcal{N} = \mathrm{tr}_B \circ \mathcal{U}_{BC}$ from the beginning of the question applied to $\rho_{AB} \otimes \rho_C$ we find
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(A:BC) &= D(\rho_{AB}\otimes \rho_C \|\rho_A\otimes \rho_B \otimes \rho_C)\\ &\geq D(\mathcal{N}(\rho_{AB} \otimes \rho_C) \|\mathcal{N}(\rho_A\otimes \rho_B \otimes \rho_C)) \\
&= D(\sigma_{AC}\|\sigma_A \otimes \sigma_C)\\
&= I(A:C)_{\sigma_{AC}}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\sigma_{AC} = \mathcal{N}(\rho_{AB} \otimes \rho_C)$ and the crucial thing to note is that after defining $\sigma_{AC}$ like this we have $\sigma_A \otimes \sigma_C = \mathcal{N}(\rho_A \otimes \rho_B \otimes \rho_C)$ which holds because $\mathcal{N}$ applies trivially on system $A$. So to answer your first question, yes, that inequality is true.

For your second inequality you write

> As such, $$I(A':B,C')\ge I(A':N(C'))$$ where $N$ is the reduced map from the actions of $U_{BC}$. As such, I would expect $$I(A':C') \ge I(A':N(C'))$$

So you have a map $\mathcal{N} = \mathrm{tr}_B \circ \mathcal{U}_{BC'}$ which maps $BC'\to C''$. By data processing you have $I(A':BC') \geq I(A':C'')$. If you just use partial trace then data processing also gives $I(A':BC') \geq I(A':C')$. What I think you are trying to imply with your notation is that there exists a map $N : C' \to C''$ such that $\mathcal{N} = N \circ \mathrm{tr}_B$. Because then you'd apply data processing twice to find $I(A':C') \geq I(A':C'')$. But this decomposition of your map is simply not true in general. For instance imagine that you take the unitary map to be the swap unitary and take your state to just be $\rho_B \otimes \rho_C$, so you swap and then trace out giving you the map $\rho_B \otimes \rho_C \mapsto \rho_B$. Now suppose you first trace out $B$, for your construction to work you need a map $N$ that sends $\rho_C \mapsto \rho_B$ and for this to be true for any $\rho_C$ and $\rho_B$ which is clearly nonsense.

**On the existence of N**

The issue seems can be boiled down to an assumption of some local dynamics. We have a channel $\mathcal{N}: BC \to C$ which consists of a global unitary followed by a partial trace, i.e.,
$$
\mathcal{N} = \mathrm{tr}_B \circ \mathcal{U}_{BC}\,.
$$
The false assumption used to justify the wrong inequality is that there exists a channel $N: C \to C$ such that
$$
\mathcal{N} = N \circ \mathrm{tr}_B\,.
$$
Let us show that in general this local channel $N$ does not exist. Assume $B$ and $C$ are isomorphic and take $\mathcal{U}_{BC}$ to be the swap channel, so $$\mathcal{U}_{BC}(\rho \otimes \sigma) = \sigma \otimes \rho\,$$
for all $\rho$ and $\sigma$. Then for all $\rho$ and $\sigma$ we must have that
$$
\mathcal{N}(\rho \otimes \sigma) = \rho\,.
$$
On the other hand, if we assume that we can also write $\mathcal{N} = N \circ \mathrm{tr}_B$ then we need for all $\sigma$ that
$$
\rho = \mathcal{N}(\rho \otimes \sigma) = N(\sigma).
$$
That is we need a channel $N$ such that $N(\sigma) = \rho$ which holds for all $\sigma$ **and** for all $\rho$. This channel clearly cannot exist because we are requiring $N(\sigma)$ to take infinitely many values, $$
\mathcal{N}(|0\rangle \langle 0| \otimes \sigma) = \sigma \implies N(\sigma) = |0 \rangle \langle 0|$$ but we also have
$$\mathcal{N}(|1\rangle \langle 1| \otimes \sigma) = \sigma \implies N(\sigma) = |1 \rangle \langle 1|$$
showing $N$ cannot exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rammus. I'm a little confused on your notation here.$\mathcal{N}=N.tr_{B}$ doesn't occur, as far as I can tell. After I get to $C'$, the only remaining map that occurs is the reduced one from interacting $B$ and $C'$, and tracing over B, obtaining $C''$. But given this is an additional map acting on it, surely $I(A':C')\ge I(A':C'')$? I am not getting this, hence my confusion. Appreciate your help.

Comment: But your map is from $BC' \to C''$. Not from $C' \to C''$ which is what you would need to justify that inequality. Please try writing down an example. It's also very easy to try the inequality numerically and you will see that it fails.

Comment: So I have mistakenly assumed that $tr_{B}\circ U_{AB}$ will have a greater affect than $tr_{B}$ on the reduction of the MI?

Comment: In a sense, yes.

Comment: So $$S(A':BC')=S(A':U_{BC}(BC'))\ge S(A':N(C'))$$ where $N()$ is the reduced dynamics on $C'$. $$Tr_{B}(\rho_{A'BC'})=I_{A}\otimes N_{C}(\rho_{A'C'})$$ Since the MI of those two is equivalent, and the MI of A' with C' for $I_{A}\otimes N_{C}(\rho_{A'C'})= S(A':N(C'))$, and that is  exactly just the reduced dynamics on C' from it's interaction with B, which is further processing, wouldn't that imply $$S(A':N(C')) \le S(A':C')?$$  Why would getting the dynamics by interacting and tracing out be different than getting the channel and applying to the reduced state? Those are equivalent processes.

Comment: Or am I wrong in stating that $N()$, acheived by $tr_{B} \circ U_{AB}$, is the same as appying the same channel to $C'$ after tracing out $B$? Apologies if this seems like a dumb question, but I feel like I have been misinterpreting something for a while then. Those two actions seem the same to me, and the same as what is described in the first part of the answer you gave.

Comment: Yes you are wrong about the existence of $N$. Please try writing down an explicit example.

Comment: See edits for a more concrete example.

Comment: Does the possiblity of non-existence of such a map stem from the loss of certain parts of C' correlated to parts of B when it is traced out, where the reduced map would then not work in the same manner vs the map that will possibly be conditoned on the parts of C's correlated to sections of B?

Comment: Yes, in the initial definition on $\mathcal{N}$ you allow the two systems to interact first which means that the reduced system on $C'$ can depend on system $B$. In the second definition you immediately throw away $B$ and so $C'$ cannot depend on $B$. My guess is that the partial trace can be done first only when the initial map is separable (but I haven't tried to prove this).

Comment: What is the actual name given to these types of maps? Clearly they aren't channels, right? They don't have an accurate kraus representation that can be locally applied to the subsystem itself and reproduce the dynamics.

Comment: They're not even maps in the usual sense. For a single input you can have many possible outputs so it's not well defined.

Comment: Is the closest accurate description just conditioned dynamics based on the part of B that C' becomes correlated to?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that